# Replace SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, case-when

I want to replace this Query

```
DECLARE @tmpUser TABLE( UserId INT, UserType INT )

INSERT INTO @tmpUser
SELECT
    u.UserId,
    1
FROM
    Users u (nolock)
WHERE
    u.UPIN = @AttendingDoctorID

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tmpUser
    SELECT
        u.UserId,
        1
    FROM
        Users u (nolock)
    WHERE
        u.FirstName = @AttendingDoctorFirstName AND
        u.LastName = @AttendingDoctorLastName
END
SELECT * FROM @tmpUser
```

to a single SQL SELECT statement without using `@tmpUser` or any other temp tables

Comment: Please consider rewriting your question. It is very unclear what you are asking - the two queries bear no relation to each other

Comment: To expand on gbn's comment... you don't need nolock in the general case.  Adding this hint will tell SQL Server not to take or honour any locks on the read data.  It can improve query performance, and especially concurrency. But this is at the expense of consistency, as you may end up reading dirty data, that is, data that is currently being updated (but has not yet been committed) by another transaction.  This probably isn't what you want, so unless you have a compelling case for using nolock (ie. a highly concurrent environment), you should probably leave it out.

Comment: @MikeyCee  : i think ...this is a highly concurrent environment...because I am calling this SP from a Thread with a time gap of 500 milli seconds. What u say ?

Comment: Highly concurrent would be like hundreds or thousands of threads all reading and updating the same data simultaneously.  I suspect that, in your case, this does not happen, though I could be wrong. By the way, 500ms is an ETERNITY in CPU cycles, though it depends on how many threads you have calling your SP.  If it's just a single thread then this would not count as highly concurrent, and you should forget about nolock (and forget about micro-optimizations in general, such as your original question, until you have a fully working app, AND you see that its performance is unacceptable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following uses an extra lookup, but it fulfills your requirements. I don't know for sure if this is any more efficient than using a temp table, though if UPIN is indexed then I suspect it would be.

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT 
        1 
    FROM 
        Users u 
    WHERE 
        u.UPIN = @AttendingDoctorID)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        u.UserId, 1 
    FROM 
        Users u  WITH(nolock)
    WHERE 
        u.UPIN = @AttendingDoctorID
END ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT
        u.UserId,
        1
    FROM
        Users u (nolock)
    WHERE
        u.FirstName = @AttendingDoctorFirstName AND
        u.LastName = @AttendingDoctorLastName
END
```

Answer (score 0):

How about Using OR instead of two separate queries.

I think it would serve the purpose.

```
SELECT
    u.UserId, 1
FROM
    Users u (nolock)
WHERE
    (u.UPIN = @AttendingDoctorID)
    OR
    (u.FirstName = @AttendingDoctorFirstName AND
    u.LastName = @AttendingDoctorLastName)
```

Comment: i don't want to use @tmpUser or any other temp tables

Comment: Then what do you want, what is the requirement. and how u need your result.

Comment: Your query is not equivalent because the original poster's query only selects a user based on name if the lookup by @AttendingDoctorID failed to match anything.

Comment: I am not sure why are you saying that, Because I am `OR`ing between the two scenarios, and if the first scenario is successful it will give the result other wise look for the second condition.

Comment: @Talha Ahmed Khan ur's is wrong see this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787540/are-both-queries-the-same/6787561#6787561

Comment: OK, Now I got that. I am sorry that I didn't picked it on the first instance.